# How can I add type annotation for the attribute that is dynamically assigned to a class?

Tags: python, type-annotation

Assume I have an existing class like below.

```
class Animal:

  name: str

  def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
    self.name = name

  def get_name(self) -> str:
    return self.name
```

And in another class, I assign another attribute to this class.

```
class Type:
  """Another class that is dynamically assigned to one of Animal attributes."""

class TestCase:

  animal: Animal

  def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
    self.animal = Animal(name)
    self.animal.type = Type()
```

How can I make a type annotation to let TestCase class knowing about `animal.type: Type`?

Comment: `self.animal.type: typing.Type[Type] = Type()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should extend your `Animal` class to define the `type` attribute

```
class TypedAnimal(Animal):

    _type: Type

class TestCase:

  animal: Animal

  def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
    self.animal = TypedAnimal(name)
    self.animal._type = Type()
```

Note, `type` is a builtin, so it is better not to use it in your code as an identifier of an attribute. You could use `_type` instead.